# CSS drop down menu - not changing on hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, mousehover

I'm having trouble with my CSS drop down menu. >.<

I want my "notifications" on the bottom menu to turn into a tab and connect to it's drop down just like the navigation menu does when you hover over it. Right now it just stays a gray oval. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gLPBP/

Answer (score 0):

Check out. http://jsfiddle.net/gLPBP/2/

Added

```
#notifications:hover {
 border-bottom-left-radius:0;
 border-bottom-right-radius:0;    
}
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you! And thank you for such a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS remove the space:

```
#notifications :hover
```

Should be

```
#notifications:hover
```

Comment: blah! I need to watch those extra spaces. >.< Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please mark as answered when you have a chance? Thanks